# SwiftUI -Unable to set frame for LPLinkView when loading Rich Links using LinkPresentation framework

Tags: swift, url, swiftui, swiftui-list, url-link

I am using LinkPresentation framework in SwiftUI project for displaying rich links in a List view. The link is getting displayed but however I am not able to set (change) the frame for the LPLinkView. LPLinkView is wrapped inside an HStack and displayed in a list.

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var redrawPreview = false
    let links: [StringLink]  = [StringLink(id: UUID(), string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXoVSbwWUIk"),
                                 StringLink(id: UUID(), string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2ojC6TNwws"),
                                 StringLink(id: UUID(), string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz6GTYaIQXU")]
    var body: some View {
        List(links) { l in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
                LinkRow(previewURL: URL(string: l.string)!, redraw: self.$redrawPreview)
            }
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50)
    }
}

struct LinkRow : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var previewURL:URL
    @Binding var redraw: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LPLinkView {
        let view = LPLinkView(url: previewURL)
        
        let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
        provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: previewURL) { (metadata, error) in
            if let md = metadata {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    view.metadata = md
                    view.sizeToFit()
                    self.redraw.toggle()
                }
            }
            else if error != nil
            {
                let md = LPLinkMetadata()
                md.title = "Custom title"
                view.metadata = md
                view.sizeToFit()
                self.redraw.toggle()
            }
        }
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: LPLinkView, context: Context) {
        // New instance for each update
    }
}

struct StringLink : Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var string : String
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you just leave the UIView at intrinsic size by removing the sizeToFit when setting it up and just have SwiftUI resize by setting the frame? Then add `.fixedSize` to the SwiftUI View to ignore offered size.

Comment: @CenkBilgen Tried the option you have suggested. It's not working.

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollView + LazyVStack` instead of `List` solved the issue.